# It seems like socket.bind isn't in the socket module

Tags: python

[Here is the error that it is showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdgZ4.png)

I use windows 7 running python 3.8.6. But it is showing that socket module does not have socket.bind.

Comment: The socket *module* indeed does not have any such thing as `.bind`.  That's an attribute of a socket *object*, that you would create via `socket.socket()` (assuming the use of `import socket`).

Answer (score 1):

you must create socket object first. then you can call socket.bind which state the 'socket' or 's' here as an object, as this example

```
import socket

HOST = ''                 # Symbolic name meaning all available interfaces
PORT = 50007              # Arbitrary non-privileged port
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `socket.socket.bind` instead.

Or change import to `from socket import socket`